# I need to change dynamic value according to response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change the value according to the response whatever I am getting in API response **this.state.basestr** that is my value when I am changing data coding API response in the different page you can see code when I am using like this I am getting an error
 `Parsing error: Unexpected token`

```
 <div className="l1-is-summary-textarea" disabled>
     {this.state.review_id != null
        ? this.state.sum.{this.state.basestr}_result
        : " "}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation), optionally with string [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<div className="l1-is-summary-textarea" disabled>
     {this.state.review_id != null
        ? this.state.sum[this.state.basestr + "_result"]
        : " "}
</div>
```

or

```
<div className="l1-is-summary-textarea" disabled>
     {this.state.review_id != null
        ? this.state.sum[`${this.state.basestr}_result`]
        : " "}
</div>
```